# Are the probiotic bacteria from formula the same bacteria present in breast milk?

Tags: health, breastfeeding, formula

Nestlé's infant formula contains probiotic bacteria. This formula is expensive, so I was wondering whether these bacteria are the same bacteria (which prevent infections and diseases) present in the breast milk?

Does my infant ****need**** these bacteria?

What is the required type of bacteria not present in the formula but present in breast milk?

Comment: NO. Breast milk has all they need. Companies such as Nestle prey on mother's fear about ensuring that their baby is properly cared for in order to sell their expensive products. Repeating, breast milk has all they need.

Comment: @DaveClarke You ve read my question backwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is almost certain they do not **need** this bacteria.

Have a look at [this question on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6180/619).

> the European Food Safety authority has researched 800 health claims of such companies, and they could not find relationships.

There is some evidence that probiotics can help in certain situations, for a small subset of the population, but that is about it.